# How to find group of rows of a table that match in another table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server,

```
Declare @Table1 Table ( TID1 INT, TP1 INT)

Declare @Table2 Table ( TID2 INT, TP2 INT)


INSERT INTO @Table1 (TID1,TP1) VALUES (100,1)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (TID1,TP1) VALUES (100,2)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (TID1,TP1) VALUES (100,3)

INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (101,1)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (101,2)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (101,3)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (102,1)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (102,2)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (103,1)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (103,2)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (103,3)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (103,4)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (104,2)
INSERT INTO @Table2 (TID2,TP2) VALUES (105,3)
```

Having Data as :

```
TID1        TP1
----------- -----------
100         1
100         2
100         3


TID2        TP2
----------- -----------
101         1
101         2
101         3
102         1
102         2
103         1
103         2
103         3
103         4
104         2
105         3
```

I want to select those records which having exact matching of TP1 column in Table2 TP2 column. EX TID2 having ID 101 will be only in result set

Comment: what you mean exact match, and what is your expected result?

Comment: not clear. TP1 in table1 has value 2 which is prsent in TP2 in table 2. why this should be excluded ?

Comment: What about 103 that also part of your result set?

Comment: 103 has 4 I guess that isnt exact match.

Comment: Yes, 103 should not be the part of result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.TID2
FROM @Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN @Table1 t1
    ON t2.TP2 = t1.TP1
GROUP BY t2.TID2
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t1.TP1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
       COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table1)
```

Comment: Yes, `COUNT(*) = 3` solve that, but I would use `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)` instead of hard code 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like below.

```
SELECT TID2
FROM   @TABLE1 T
       RIGHT JOIN  @TABLE2 T2
         ON T.TP1 = T2.TP2
GROUP  BY TID2
HAVING COUNT(T2.TP2) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TABLE1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- you can calculated this in CTEW or sub-query if you do not like to be in variable
DECLARE @MaxRowsCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table1);

SELECT T2.[TID2]
FROM @Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN @Table1 T1
    ON T2.[TP2] = T1.[TP1]
GROUP BY T2.[TID2]
HAVING
(
    -- current count of rows should be the same as the row count from the first table
    COUNT(T2.[TP2]) = @MaxRowsCount
)
```